# variable in flash returning as "undefined"

Tags: php, flash

i have a variable in flash that takes its value from a php file using the print function.

The variable is not returning the correct value. It's returning "undefined". I have checked of both flash and php source code for errors, they both seem the be fine.

anyone know what could be causing this?

php print code:

```
print "return_sponsor=$sponsor";
```

flash code:

```
function completeHandler(event:Event):void{
    // Clear the form fields
    name_txt.text = "";
    email_txt.text = "";
    MovieClip(parent).gotoAndPlay("finish");
    // Load the response from the PHP file 
    variables.sponny = event.target.data.return_sponsor;
```

Comment: Can you share any related code surrounding the problem line?

Comment: What do you see if you trace the value of you urlLoader's `data` property after the complete event?

Comment: I'm testing it on a remote server so i cannot use the trace function. or can i? :S

Comment: this has only recently started to happen. I haven't changed anything, it just started to happen.

Comment: In the php file, there are several other php files included. I removed all the included php files and it works now. I need to include those php files though. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Sounds like maybe a PHP error is causing the issue, make sure PHP errors are enabled and see if any are output that is preventing your script from reaching the output routine.

Comment: i've had this problem before (where including files was causing problems). Last time it was just a simple typo in one of the included files. Ive checked over and over now, there is nothing wrong with any of the included files and the main php file.

Comment: @nav: for future reference, you can trace in the browser in a number of ways.  Monster Debugger is very good, it's a standalone AIR app the reads your executing SWF files if you compile it into your projects.  For something like this though, I find the easiest way is to Use Firefox/Firebug and do something like `if(ExternalInterface.available) ExternalInterface.call('console.log','Trace this text');`

Answer (score 0):

I've not used AS3 in a while, but this might work.

Replace:

```
variables.sponny = event.target.data.return_sponsor;
```

With:

```
var data:URLVariables = new URLVariables(event.target.data);
variables.sponny = data.return_sponsor;
```

Comment: hey, same thing happens. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what type your sponny variable is but that error is generally returned when Flash can't convert types correctly.  It happens to me if I am trying to convert a string to a Number or int (or some other numeric type) and there is a non-numeric symbol in the string (so "12a4" would not be able to convert properly for example).

When you are debugging, place event.target.data.return_sponsor in a String variable and check that it is the correct data.  If you can't debug, you may have to find a way to show the data on the screen somehow (maybe by printing them to the form?)

```
name_txt.text = event.target.data.return_sponsor;
```

Comment: hey, I've found the problem but cant seem to fix it. I have several included files in the php file. When i remove those included files, it works fine. But i need those php files included.